# How to plot a sphere from the standard equation?

Tags: plotting

```
Plot3D[z^2 = -(x^2 + y^2), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

This is the code I used but it's giving a

Comment: Have you seen `ContourPlot3D[]`?

Answer (score 9):

The equation for a sphere is `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == r^2`

```
With[{r = 7.5},
 ContourPlot3D[r^2 == (x^2 + y^2 + z^2),
  {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  PlotRange -> {-10, 10},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"},
  ViewPoint -> Front]]
```

[image]

To use `Plot3D` you must solve for both solutions for `z`

```
With[{r = 7.5},
 Plot3D[{
   Sqrt[r^2 - x^2 - y^2],
   -Sqrt[r^2 - x^2 - y^2]},
  {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"},
  ViewPoint -> Front]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use `RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]`.

[image: Plotting a sphere with RegionPlot3D]